# Working with Nibbles in C#

Tags: c#, java, javascript, .net, xna

Hey I want to write a struct like the XNA Color struct or the SurfaceFormat.Bgra4444 struct that holds 2 nibbles in a 8 bit byte.

This is what I have so far...

```
/// <summary>
/// Packed byte containing two 4bit values
/// </summary>
public struct Nibble2 : IEquatable<Nibble2>
{
    private byte packedValue;

    public byte X
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }

    public byte Y
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of this object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Initial value for the x component.</param>
    /// <param name="y">Initial value for the y component.</param>
    public Nibble2(float x, float y)
    {
        packedValue = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of this object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector">Input value for both components.</param>
    public Nibble2(Vector2 vector)
    {
        packedValue = 0;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Nibble2 a, Nibble2 b) { return a.packedValue == b.packedValue; }
    public static bool operator !=(Nibble2 a, Nibble2 b) { return a.packedValue != b.packedValue; }

    public override string ToString()
    { return packedValue.ToString("X : " + X + " Y : " + Y, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {return packedValue;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Nibble2)
            return Equals((Nibble2)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Nibble2 other)
    {return packedValue == other.packedValue;}
}
```

As you can see my propertys and constructors are not implimented. As this is the part I am having trouble with.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you just need to keep in mind what is the high and low nibbles. The low nibble can be obtained just by masking with binary 1111 (decimal 15). The high nibble can be obtained (since `byte` is unsigned) by right-shifting by 4. The rest is just bit-math.

```
// assume x is the low nibble
public byte X
{
    get { return (byte)(packedValue & 15); }
    set { packedValue = (packedValue & 240) | (value & 15); }
}

// assume y is the high nibble
public byte Y
{
    get { return (byte) (packedValue >> 4); }
    set { packedValue = (value << 4) | (packedValue & 15); }
}
```

I can't, however, help you with:

```
public Nibble2(float x, float y)
{
    packedValue = 0;
}
```

because that is 64 bits, and you want to fit it into 8. You'd need to be a **lot** more specific about what you want to do with those values.

Comment: I wanted that function to just take in 2 bytes (from 0, to 15) but I can just make that use the propertys to set the values.

Thanks you are great help!

Marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following byte value:

```
10101100
```

To read the high bits of a byte, you should shift the bytes to the right:

```
10101100 (original)
01010110 (shifted one bit)
00101011  
00010101 
00001010 (shifted four bits)
```

You can shift bytes by using `return (byte)(packedValue >> 4);`

To read just the low bits, you simply eliminate the top bits using an AND opertation:

```
10101100 
00001111 AND
--------
00001100
```

You can perform this AND operation on a value by using `return (byte)(packedValue & 0xf);`

Setting these values can be performed by clearing the target nibble and then simply adding the input value (shifted left if setting the high nibble):

```
packedValue = (byte)((packedValue & 0xf0) + (lowNibble & 0xf));
packedValue = (byte)((packedValue & 0xf) + (highNibble << 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you AND the input value with byte filled like this `00001111` which is 15 in dec. You keep the part that you want to save. Then you'll have to left shift the left part of your Nibble2 with 4 bytes to store in the packedValue byte.

```
private byte x = 0;
private byte y = 0;


public byte X
{
    get { return x; }
    set { x = value}
}

public byte Y
{
    get { return y; }
    set { y = value }
}

private byte packedValue 
{
    get { return (x & 15 << 4) | (y & 15); }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to preserve the other half of the original value

Comment: (after edit) += is invariable a bad idea with bit-ops; frankly, I'd stick to `packedValue += ((value & 15) << 4) | (packedValue & 15)` etc

Comment: Sorry @MarcGravell I'm not really following you :). And I'm not ashamed to say so hehe.

Comment: no problem; ok; for the "+=" issue, set X = 4, now set X = 5, now set X = 4. What is X ? For the "preserve old value" issue; set X = 4, Y = 5; now... what is X?

Comment: I want to be able to set the X or Y seperately without losing the data in either. Also how would I mask the data for the get assessors to retreave the data?

Comment: with your further edit, you aren't really "packing" anything. It'll *work*, but seems to now be missing the point. Oh, and I *still* advise to use `|` rather than `+` when you are dealing with masks.

Comment: Right yes. "Fixing" it like this seemed to me to be the shortest route to deal with the issues you pointed out in the comments. And since you posted the other solution I'll leave mine like this. I learned again today :)